# Sets arrange strings in lexicographical order and integers in ascending order

Tags: python

Sets are called unordered collection of elements or items right?
Then why it is ordered when I run integers in a set. When I run any strings, they will be ordered alphabetically. I do not understand this. Please explain

Ex 1: When we run

```
a = {"tammy", "rick", "morty"}
```

it gives

```
{'morty', 'rick', 'tammy'}
```

which is in alphabetical order!

Ex 2: When we run

```
b = {23,56,43,76,856}
```

It gives

```
{23, 43, 56, 76, 856}
```

which is in ascending order!

Comment: "Unordered" means that it is not possible for two sets to differ by order in a meaningful sense.  If you compare two sets with the same elements specified in different orders, you'll see that they're considered equal, because order is explicitly not significant in a set.

Comment: This accidental ordering is not a part of set properties in Python and it only happens with small integers.

Comment: @pavel can you give an example where this does not hold true?

Comment: `b = {-97, 1}` => `{1, -97}`

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I tried the same example but surprisingly, I see the ordering there as well!

Answer (score 0):

Having looked into the source code of python set [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/setobject.c), I think it is due to the way sets are implemented. The hashing causes a certain level of order but this also means as the set size increases and the number of hash collisions increase, the order that you see, will disappear.

I did some experiments and here are my observations:

1. Assume, you have a variable `a = {1,-97}`, then printing the variable `a` would give you `{-97,1}` (an ordered representation) but printing the elements one by one would give you any random order.
2. Generating a random big set using

```
a = set([random.randint(10000, 1e15) for i in range(n)])
```

gives an ordering as explained in point 1 for `n<=999`, but starting from `n=1000` the ordering vanishes.

**NOTE**: These are mere observations and not facts.

But to answer your question, I can say that what you are observing is not applicable for all sets!

Answer (score -2):

In case of strings sets store those in lexicographical order i.e nothing but in dictionary order